# Is there a way to retrieve the aggregated notification from GetStream webhook

Tags: getstream-io

I have connected my project to the webhook that GetStream provide. The access is established, but i only receive the single-notification and not the aggregated-notification.

The idea is to connect the webhook to a push-notification service.

I have had a look at their documentation: https://getstream.io/docs/ios/#realtime-webhooks, where they provide an example. But i can only access the single-notification as i see it.

```
[
    {
      "deleted":[],
      "new":[{"actor":"1","verb":"tweet","object":"1","target":null,"time":"2014-12-15T17:20:37.258","foreign_id":null,"id":"af781804-847e-11e4-8080-80012fb97b9e","tweet":"Hello world"}],
      "published_at":"2014-12-15T17:20:37.263518+00:00",
      "feed":"user:2",
      "app_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "deleted":["38f81366-847f-11e4-9c94-0cc47a024be0"],
      "new":[],
      "published_at":"2014-12-15T17:20:37.263518+00:00",
      "feed":"timeline:1",
      "app_id": "123"
    }
]
```

I was thinking about querying the aggregated-notification or single-notification to check if it already exist, but the only way is to query it by foreign-key and it's not the aggregation-keys.

I want to know if i somehow can get the aggregated-notification (**activity_count**). Instead of getting every single-notification, because the idea is the send a push-notification for every created aggregated-notification only.

Comment: the snippet you pasted is for an activity added to a flat feed, realtime updates sent for adds to aggregated feeds (and notification feeds) include the activity group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to receive an aggregated notification via realtime notification system. Grouping is happening at feed read time but notification is sent the moment you add an activity to feed so grouping information is not available at that time.

You could read the feed with limit of 1 to get check which group activity ended up in

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it make sense that i can't get the information right away.
- So just to clarify, i query the feed with limit 1 and receive the last added activity this way. Without using the group that is received?

Comment: It actually depends on your feed aggregation rule. You might need to request more than 1 group from feed.
The idea is to read top few feeds and find the group your new activity is part of.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the notification through the webhook, <s>you can use the activity data and the aggregation format you set up for your feed to build the aggregation identifier and then retrieve additional information about the group</s> your activities will contain group information (notice the `group` field). For example when adding an activity to a notification feed you might get data like this:

```
[
  {
    "new": [
      {
        "actor": "jhon",
        "foreign_id": "foood:1",
        "group": "eat_2019-01-13",
        "heat": "very",
        "id": "36d466f4-1715-11e9-8080-800169b0b807",
        "object": "food:1336",
        "origin": null,
        "target": "",
        "time": "2019-01-13T09:25:49.315250",
        "verb": "eat"
      }
    ],
    "deleted": [],
    "feed": "timeline_aggregated:feed_id",
    "app_id": xxxxx,
    "published_at": "2019-06-13T14:47:31.368Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: That sounds promising, can you provide any documentation on this. Because i can't find anything on how to query the aggregation identifier.

Comment: How do i use the group to retrieve the _aggregated activity_?
I can't get access to the _aggregated-id_, which seems to be the only way to use getActivityDetails() - if i specify the **not** _aggregated activity id_, it returns a wrong activity. @Mircea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613463/getstream-io-using-getactivities-with-an-aggregated-feed-id - i found this useful, but i retrieve the wrong activity, unless i specify the _aggregated-id_. Which i can't access?

Comment: I was preparing a reply in the vein of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613463/getstream-io-using-getactivities-with-an-aggregated-feed-id, but I'm not sure I understand why you can't access the `aggregated-id`. The example you posted is the webhook payload for a flat feed, where you wouldn't get any group information. If you're listening to events on an aggregated feed, you will get the group identifier.

Comment: That's correct, i get the _group-identifier_ from the webhook. But how do i get the details from that _group-identifier_. Just to clarify: if i open an aggregated-actvitiy in the GetStream console, it's has an **ID** - **Group** - **Created At** - **Updated At**, which one does the _group-identifer_ refer to?

Comment: The `ID` in the Dashboard refers to the activity ID, which you can use to retrieve the sole activity with `client.getActivities` and `Group` in the dashboard refers to the group identifier which you can use in the `feed.get` call.

Comment: I'm trying to use feed.get, but get an error **is not a valid UUID** - which my group isn't. Is that expected?