# GetStream - How do i query an aggregated activity by it's group

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to query an aggregated activity, by it's group.

**Use case**: Trying to query an aggregated activity, to get the *activity_count*.

I have tried **feed.get**, but i can only make it work if i use *group.id*, but i don't know how i am able to get *group.id* from the *group* that i am retrieving from the webhook.

> feed.get(id_lte=group, id_gte=group, limit=1 )

I have also tried **getActivityDetail** but it returns another aggregated activity.

> feed.getActivityDetail(activity.id) - *(not aggregated activity, retrieved from the webhook)*

Anyone knows how to query the aggregated activity?

Related links: [Is there a way to retrieve the aggregated notification from GetStream webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543022/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-aggregated-notification-from-getstream-webhook/56547164?noredirect=1#comment101700299_56547164) , [getstream-io: Using getActivities with an aggregated feed id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613463/getstream-io-using-getactivities-with-an-aggregated-feed-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to get group ID via realtime notification system. Group ID is only available when reading from the feed itself

You could read the feed with limit of 1 every time you receive the notification to check which group activity ended up in.